# Laravel eloquent get count using withCount() and add where clause on it

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a query like below to get count of punches on users relationship and then want to add where clause to check if count is greater then 3 or not to get only those users having punches count is more than 3.

```
$repeatedlyLatemark = User::withCount(['punches'=> fn($q)=> $q
                ->where('is_latemark', '1')
                ->whereDate('punch_date', '>=', Carbon::today()->startOfMonth()->toDateString())
                ->whereDate('punch_date', '<=', Carbon::today()->endOfMonth()->toDateString())
            ])
            ->having('punches_count', '>', '3')
            ->when(!$is_admin, fn($q)=> $q->where('department_id', $authUser->department_id) )
            ->when($ward, fn($q)=> $q->where('ward_id', $ward))
            ->count();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you could reuse that anonymous function in a `whereHas('punches', $function, '>', 3)`  potentially ... giving you Users only having greater than 3 punches that meet your criteria

Comment: Do you need count of punches in your collection ? if not then @lagbox  has the right answer for you !

Comment: By the way your query seems works fine ! what the issue you get ?

Comment: @lagbox I have used that also but it keeps on loading until request timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Use integer, not string '3'

```
$repeatedlyLatemark = User::withCount(['punches'=> fn($q)=> $q
            ->where('is_latemark', '1')
            ->whereDate('punch_date', '>=', Carbon::today()->startOfMonth()->toDateString())
            ->whereDate('punch_date', '<=', Carbon::today()->endOfMonth()->toDateString())
        ])
        ->having('punches_count', '>', 3)  // Note: Use integer, not string '3'
        ->when(!$is_admin, fn($q)=> $q->where('department_id', $authUser->department_id) )
        ->when($ward, fn($q)=> $q->where('ward_id', $ward))
        ->count();
```